# wro4j less processing fails for bootstrap 3.1.0

Tags: maven, twitter-bootstrap, less, wro4j

I'm running wro4j-maven-plugin 1.7.3 against the latest bootstrap less sources (3.1.0) and get the following exception:

```
Failed to execute goal ro.isdc.wro4j:wro4j-maven-plugin:1.7.3:run (default) on project     dezolve-web: Exception occured while processing: ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException: Could not execute the script because:
[ERROR] {
[ERROR] "type": "Parse",
[ERROR] "message": "Syntax Error on line 1476",
[ERROR] "index": 43910.0,
[ERROR] "filename": null,
[ERROR] "line": 1476.0,
[ERROR] "column": 25.0,
[ERROR] "extract": [
[ERROR] "  padding-right: (@grid-gutter-width / 2);",
[ERROR] "  &:extend(.clearfix all);",
[ERROR] "}"
[ERROR] ]
[ERROR] }, class: ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException,caused by:
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I get the same problem in m2e - it this relating to Bootstrap needing a newer version of LESS?

Comment: Have you tried using less4j processor instead of lessCss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @alexo's comment above, changing using the less4j processor over the lessCss processor has resolved this issue.

So my wro.properties now looks like:

```
preProcessors=cssImport,semicolonAppender   
postProcessors=less4j,cssMinJawr
```